# Accessing system catalog views of netezza from SSIS package not working

Tags: ssis, netezza

I am trying to run following query from the SSIS package sql task to netezza database:

```
select t.table_name
from   tables      t,
       columns     c
where t.table_name like 'AB%'
 and  t.table_name = c.table_name
 and  c.column_name = 'XYZ'
```

Query runs perfectly on different editor like Aginity workbench, however SSIS package is not giving any output and it's keep running without any result.

I am not sure if SSIS is having limitations related to accessing system catalog views of other data source.

Please suggest if anyone came across same issue.

Regards,
Om

Comment: Why do you talk about ‘system catalog’? These look like normal tables.... what’s the error you get ?

Comment: There are system tables and in the netezza world it is called system catalog tables/views, in SQL we call those system tables. I am not getting any error, it's running infinitely without any result other queries are running without any issues.

Comment: We have a mystery on our hands.... is the query inside SSIS the Exact same?

Comment: Btw: you do not need to join to ‘tables’ in this example.... does it work if you don’t?

Comment: Hi 'Lars G Olsen', yes, query in the SSIS package is exact same (only column name and table name are different as per my requirement). No in any case if i am trying to access the system tables it doesn't work with SQL Task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your time and trying to look on the issue which i am facing.

As an alternative solution, i am using Script Task (C# programming) and same query is working fine without any issue.

However not sure why SQL Task is not working.

So i am marking this as an solution. Happy to see any response which will have solution for the SQL Task approach, which is easy to support (loosely coupling).

Comment: The exact whereclauses MAY be relevant. If the query plan against the ‘postgres’ catalog tables is different because of cardinality estimates, a ‘infinite’ runtime could very well be the result....